# PostgreSQL concurrent check if row exists in table

Tags: postgresql, concurrency

Suppose I have simple logic:
If user had no balance accrual earlier (which is recorded in `accruals` table), we must give him 100$ to balance:

```
START TRANSACTION;
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $$
DECLARE _accrual accruals;
BEGIN
  --LOCK TABLE accruals; -- label A
  SELECT * INTO _accrual from accruals WHERE user_id = 1;
  IF _accrual.accrual_id IS NOT NULL THEN
    RAISE SQLSTATE '22023';
  END IF;
  UPDATE users SET balance = balance + 100 WHERE user_id = 1;
  INSERT INTO accruals (user_id, amount) VALUES (1, 100);
END
$$;
COMMIT;
```

The problem of this transaction is it's not concurrent.
Running this transaction in parrallel results getting `user_id=1` with `balance=200` and 2 accruals recorded.

How do I test concurrency ?
1. I run in session 1: `START TRANSACTION; LOCK TABLE accruals;`
2. In session 2 and session 3 I run this transaction
3. In session 1: `ROLLBACK`

The question is: How do I make this 100% concurrent and make sure user will have 100$ only once.
The only way I see is to lock the table (`label A` in code sample)

But do I have another way ?

Comment: What is the primary key of the table `accruals`?

Comment: It is `accrual_id`

Comment: So one user can have multiple rows in there?

Comment: Yeah, thats right

Comment: Your update statement is updating every row.  Certainly that can't be correct?

Comment: @jjanes Yes, sorry. This is actually a simplified version of real code with hardcoded values. Edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to use the serializable isolation level (by changing default_transaction_isolation).  Then one of the processes should get something like "ERROR:  could not serialize access due to concurrent update"

If you want to keep the isolation level at 'read committed', then you can just count accruals at the end and throw an error:

```
START TRANSACTION;
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $$
DECLARE _accrual accruals;
        _count int;
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO _accrual from accruals WHERE user_id = 1;
  IF _accrual.accrual_id IS NOT NULL THEN
    RAISE SQLSTATE '22023';
  END IF;
  UPDATE users SET balance = balance + 100 WHERE user_id = 1;
  INSERT INTO accruals (user_id, amount) VALUES (1, 100);
  select count(*) into _count from accruals where user_id=1;
  IF _count >1 THEN
    RAISE SQLSTATE '22023';
  END IF;
END
$$;
COMMIT;
```

This works because one process will block the other on the UPDATE (assuming non-zero number of rows get updated), and by the time one process commits to release the blocked process, its inserted row will be visible to the other one.

Formally there is then no need for the first check, but if you don't want a lot of churn due to rolled back INSERT and UPDATE, you might want to keep it.